# Bash script to return exit code from NodeJs script

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash

I have a Bash script which runs a node script as part of its tasks. I would like the bash script to exit with the same exit code as the node script. Simplified example below.

foo.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
node ./bar.js
```

bar.js:

```
process.exit(1); //sometimes the exit code can be 0
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html

> When a script ends with an exit that has no parameter, the exit status of the script is the exit status of the last command executed in the script

which implies that you simply need to add "exit" to your above script.

```
#!/bin/bash
node ./bar.js
exit
```

Answer (score 5):

Bash stores the exit code of the previous command in a variable named `$?`

```
#!/bin/bash
node ./bar.js
# will print nodes exit code, e.g. 0 for success
echo $?
```

**EDIT**

Once you have the exit code you can decide what to do, including exiting as mentioned in the other answer

Comment: Please provide feedback if down voting. Thanks

Comment: I downvoted because (initially) you didn't mention anything about how to make the bash script exit with a certain value, which is what the OP wanted to do. You only described how to obtain the exit code of the previous command.

Comment: @jangler Fair enough! I just wanted to make sure there wasn't anything else I had missed.